# Material-UI Popover: anchorPosition issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a vertical timeline with Cards alternating sides as you go down the timeline, I want to implement a Popover with a new, more detailed Card on the opposite side of a given Card on the timeline. However, MaterialUI's Popover only has the option of left in it's anchorPosition prop. Is there a work around to have this prop have an option to place right, including an offset to have it display across the timeline?

Using anchorOrigin displays it to the right but without an offset.

Here's what the code for a popover that should go to the right looks like.

```
   <Button
                  size="small"
                  color="primary"
                  component={Link}
                  //to={card.path}
                  onClick={e => {
                    this.handlePop(e, i);
                  }}
                >
                  Learn More
                </Button>
                <Popover
                  open={this.state.popped === i}
                  anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
                  anchorReference="anchorOrigin"
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    horizontal: "right",
                    vertical: "top "
                  }}
                  transformOrigin={{
                    horizontal: "right",
                    vertical: "center"
                  }}
                  anchorPosition={ {top: 200, left: 400 }}
                  onClose={this.handleRequestClose}
                >
                  <div>
                    <Card className="card">
                      <CardActionArea>
                        <CardMedia
                          style={{ height: 0, paddingTop: "100%" }}
                          image={card.image}
                        />
                        <CardContent>
                          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                            {card.title}
                          </Typography>
                          <Typography component="p">{card.subtitle}</Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                      </CardActionArea>
                    </Card>
                  </div>
                </Popover>
```

[image: Here's a screenshot of the current situation. I want the new popover card to pop into the whitespace on the opposite side of the timeline.]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Popover documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/), you can use `anchorReference` and `anchorPosition` instead of `anchorEl`. I believe this is what you're looking for - just play with the example.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue now, so i used `styled components` to add an `offset` prop from outside like so:

```
import React, { ReactElement, useEffect } from "react";
import { Popover, PopoverProps } from "@material-ui/core";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Positions, position as popoverPosition } from "./positions";

const getOffsetTranslation = (position: Positions, offset: number) => {
  switch (position) {
    case Positions.RightBottom:
      return `translateX(${offset}px)`;

    case Positions.LeftBottom:
      return `translateX(-${offset}px)`;

    case Positions.LeftTop:
      return `translateX(-${offset}px)`;

    case Positions.RightTop:
      return `translateX(${offset}px)`;

    case Positions.BottomRight:
      return `translateY(${offset}px)`;

    case Positions.BottomLeft:
      return `translateY(${offset}px)`;

    case Positions.TopLeft:
      return `translateY(-${offset}px)`;

    case Positions.TopRight:
      return `translateY(-${offset}px)`;
  }
};

const PopoverStyled = styled(Popover) <PopoverMUIProps>`
  ${({ position = Positions.RightBottom, offset = 0 }) => `
    & .MuiPopover-paper {
      transform: ${getOffsetTranslation(position, offset)}!important;
    }
    `}
`;

export interface PopoverMUIProps extends Partial<PopoverProps> {
  contentComponent?: ReactElement;
  offset?: number;
  position?: Positions;
  isOpen?: boolean;
  onClick?: (args?: any) => void;
}

const defaultElement = <button>Open Popover</button>;

const PopoverMUI = (props: PopoverMUIProps) => {
  const {
    children = defaultElement,
    contentComponent,
    offset,
    position = Positions.RightBottom,
    isOpen,
    onClick = () => null,
  } = props;

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "popover-mui" : undefined;

  useEffect(() => {
    !isOpen && handleClose();
  }, [isOpen])

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    onClick(event)
  };




  return (
    <div>
      <div aria-describedby={id} onClick={handleClick}>
        {children}
      </div>
      <PopoverStyled
        {...{ offset, id, open, anchorEl, position }}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={popoverPosition[position].anchorOrigin}
        transformOrigin={popoverPosition[position].transformOrigin}>
        {contentComponent}
      </PopoverStyled>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PopoverMUI;
```